# How to resolve an "ARRAY_LITERAL" error in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays

Keep getting the "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows" error for this query:

```
=query({'Silent Auction Items'!A2:B263;'Raffle Tickets'!A2:B74,'Winner''s Choice Raffle'!A2:B74;'Greeting Cards'!A2:B74;'Live Auction Items'!A2:B27;'Dessert Dash'!A2:B74;'Heads or Tails Raffle'!A2:B74;Ask!A2:B74;'Credit Card Fee Donation'!A2:B74;'Other Donation'!A2:B74},"select * where Col1=133")
```

I tested this with each tab separately (e.g., **{'Silent Auction Items'!A2:B263}**) and it worked each time, returning the same number of columns if there was no purchase in a category (i.e., **133, $0.00**), so I'm not finding the problem yet.

Each tab is for a different category of purchase bidders can make at an auction. Col1 in each tab is a BidderNumber field. So, in this example, I'm filtering for all the purchases made by Bidder 133.

(Larger background: Trying to repurpose an MS Access database for Google Sheets, which is more familiar to our volunteers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comma instead of semi-colon here `'Raffle Tickets'!A2:B74,'Winner''s Choice Raffle'!A2:B74`, so try

```
=query({'Silent Auction Items'!A2:B263;'Raffle Tickets'!A2:B74;'Winner''s Choice Raffle'!A2:B74;'Greeting Cards'!A2:B74;'Live Auction Items'!A2:B27;'Dessert Dash'!A2:B74;'Heads or Tails Raffle'!A2:B74;Ask!A2:B74;'Credit Card Fee Donation'!A2:B74;'Other Donation'!A2:B74},"select * where Col1=133")
```

Comment: Sharp eye! That did the trick. Thanks much